# Azure LogicManagementClient returning "Attempted to access an element as a type incompatible with the array." error during initialization

Tags: c#, azure, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to retrieve the Azure logic app actions' execution history using LogicManagementClient however getting 'Attempted to access an element as a type incompatible with the array.' error at below line -

```
LogicManagementClient client = new LogicManagementClient(credentials) { SubscriptionId = "****" };
```

The credentials object is created successfully and I could see the values while debugging -

```
var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory
                .FromServicePrincipal("clientid",
                    "clientsecret",
                    "tenantid",
                    AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
```

Below is the stack trace -

```
System.ArrayTypeMismatchException
  HResult=0x80131503
  Message=Attempted to access an element as a type incompatible with the array.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Add(T item)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.Logic.LogicManagementClient.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.Logic.LogicManagementClient..ctor(ServiceClientCredentials credentials, DelegatingHandler[] handlers)
```

Appreciate any suggestions to overcome the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the issue by adding below in the app.config file in the project that was referencing the earlier mentioned code -

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```